# GLSL 3.30 is not supported (Ubuntu 12.04, Intel HD Graphics 3000 and NVIDIA Graphics with Optimus)

Tags: intel-graphics, opengl

The system:
Dell Latitude E6520

Video Card

```
Intel® HD Graphics 3000
NVIDIA® NVSTM 4200M (DDR3 512MB) Discrete Graphics with Optimus
```

Ubuntu 12.04

I installed bumblebee.

I installed PyOpenGL and am following the tutorial (http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/shader_1.xhtml)

Result on Python says:

---

```
RuntimeError: ('Shader compile failure (0): 0:1(10): error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.00 ES, 1.10, 1.20, and 1.30\n\n', ['#version 330\n        void main() {\n            gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;\n        }'], GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
```

---

I know NVIDIA Graphics with Optimus can not be supported on Ubuntu.
But I think Intel Graphics should support the latest version of OpenGL.

1. What should I do? Can I update something like drivers to make Intel Graphics support the GLSL 3.30?
2. If I can not, how can I use lower version of OpenGL in PyOpenGL? 
   On http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/, it writes:
   PyOpenGL 3.0.2 includes support for:
   OpenGL v1.1 through 4.3

So there would be an option to set OpenGL at a lower version. But I failed to find the way to do it.

Help!! Thanks in advance!

[Update]
(1)

> So there would be an option to set OpenGL at a lower version. But I
>   failed to find the way to do it.

I found the option in the code. Need to specify the version; of course, consequently some code too.

(2) From the wiki/GLSL#Versions, the corresponding GLSL versions are

> GLSL version   OpenGL version
>   1.30.10   3.0
>   1.40.08   3.1
>   1.50.11   3.2
>   3.30.6            3.3

So it seems Intel Graphics 3000 support OpenGL Version 3.0.

I went to the Intel official website and Linux driver website, fail to find the answer. 
(Drivers for Linux*
(I am not allowed to post more than 2 links :(

Linux Graphics
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/search/node/HD%20Graphics%203000)

But now I almost know I will use OpenGL 3.0 and only follow tutorials for OpenGL 3.0. Who could recommend good ones?

Comment: as it seems, Intel is still working on OpenGL 3.1 for Linux , best bet would be to use your Nvidia card with the proprietary driver for the task.

Comment: If you have the latest intel linux graphics stack, you need to specify that you want glsl `#version 330 core`

Comment: What CPU exactly is it?

Comment: Also, you should seriously consider upgrading to at least 14.04, if not 16.04, which have much newer Xorg/Mesa stacks.

Comment: Your CPU only supports OpenGL 3.1, and GLSL 3.30 requires at least OpenGL 3.3 support, so you can't use GLSL 3.30 features on this Intel GPU. At least the NVidia proprietary drivers should enable newer versions of OpenGL on that chip, allowing GLSL 3.30 or some newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this question accidentally and thought, maybe someone is facing the same today ...

Your **NVIDIA NVSTM 4200M** graphics is supported by the latest official **NVIDIA drivers 355.11** !
Completely remove all NVIDIA software and replace it with the NVIDIA drivers 355 and Optimus.

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and password. Now uninstall every NVIDIA related software by executing:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee  
sudo reboot
```

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and password. Now reinstall the NVIDIA drivers by executing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

For further information about the NVIDIA 355 drivers release refer to the [NVIDIA release notes](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/90393/en-us).

You can check the OpenGL version with :

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
sudo glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

The output shows something like this :

```
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 355.11
```